# Is there a simpler way to find arithmetic sequences from three sets of numbers?

Tags: python, sequence

I have three sets of numbers, from which the goal is to find as many sets that form an arithmetic sequence as possible. I know that one set corresponds to the first number of each sequence, and so on. With these (shortened) versions of the lists, what would be a way to find the sequences? My only idea up until now was nested for loops, which worked for smaller lists but began to take too long with the full lists.

```
clist = [7, 11, 52, 102, 144, 314]
tlist = [10, 29, 79, 94, 121, 146]
flist = [13, 47, 184, 190, 544, 649]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: look for itertools https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html

Comment: Please update your post with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

So first you want the empty set, every set of just one element, and every set of just two elements, since all of these are arguably an arithmetic series by technicality:

```
series = [[]]

for j in range(len(clist)):

    series.append([clist[j]])
    series.append([tlist[j]])
    series.append([flist[j]])

    for k in range(len(clist)):
        series.append([clist[j],tlist[k]])
        series.append([clist[j],flist[k]])
        series.append([flist[j],tlist[k]])
        series.append([flist[j],clist[k]])
        series.append([tlist[j],clist[k]])
        series.append([tlist[j],flist[k]])
        if j != k:
                 series.append([tlist[j],tlist[k]])  
                 series.append([clist[j],clist[k]])
                 series.append([flist[j],flist[k]])
```

I excluded the case where j = k because otherwise there are infinitely many solutions where each element is the same and the characteristic difference is 0 (e.g. [13], [13,13,13,13,13,13], [13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13] ...)

So "series" now includes every arithmetic sequence you can make from these lists of length 0, 1, or 2. The next step is to check the difference between each of the elements in every 2-length arithmetic sequence, and to write code that checks for a number being that difference more again. For example, the list [7, 10] has a difference of 3 so the next element that could make the list is "13". We can write code that first checks all the lists currently in series, then checks if there is a number in any of the lists which is the characteristic difference of the series more than the last element, and if there is, appends a new list (which is the old list plus the new element) to the list of series.

This question sounds vaguely homework-y so I won't do it for you, but hopefully my comment makes it clear what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

An arithmetic sequence is fully described by two parameters, the *initial value* and a *common difference*. `list1` is assumed to contain all initial values, `list2` and `list3` represents the candidates for the next terms in the sequence. Find the common difference between `list1` and `list2`, then between `list2` and `list3`. Check then if same common difference. If it the case the you have an arithmetic sequence.

```
list1 = [7, 11, 52, 102, 144, 314]
list2 = [10, 29, 79, 94, 121, 146]
list3 = [13, 47, 184, 190, 544, 649]


cd1 = [] # list of common differences between list1 and list2
for l1 in list1:
    cd1 += [(l1, i2, i2 - l1) for i2 in list2]


cd2 = [] # list of common differences between list2 and list3
for l2 in list2:
    cd2 += [(l2, i3, i3 - l2) for i3 in list3]


arithmetics_seqs = []
for d1 in cd1:
    # check if same common differences between cd1 and cd2
    arithmetics_seqs += [d1[:2]+(d2[1],) for d2 in cd2 if d2[-1] == d1[-1]]

print(arithmetics_seqs)
```

Output

```
[(7, 10, 13), (11, 29, 47), (52, 121, 190), (102, 146, 190)]
```

Comment: Is there a way I can modify this for if the lists have different lengths?

Comment: @Jmaxmanblue I don't know what you mean... I am not even sure if I my guess was right. Could you provide an example of your ideal output? What do you mean by different lengths? There are 3 layers... with 2 would be ridiculous... with more modified the question or make a new one

Answer (score 0):

i may not have the best computational method, however, i think this would work for you - of course, the larger the list, the larger the compute time.

```
list1 = [2,4,7]
list2 = [4,8,10]
list3 = [6,8,9]
for l1 in list1:
   for l2 in list2:
       for l3 in list3:
           x = l1 - l2
           y = l2 - l3
           if x and y != 0:
              if x == y:
                 print(l1,l2,l3, " = arithmetic sequence Found")
```